# error: Installing Bundler "Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6"

Tags: react-native, path, rubygems, bundler, macos-monterey

## I've tried all the path solutions described in the same problem opened here but without success so I opened a new question.

The error says that my ruby version is 2.6.10 but as you can see in the         terminal beside the version is 2.7.6. And I tried running the suggested update 'gem update --system 3.2.3 ' the terminal response is "Latest version already installed. Done."

I think the error is when configuring the dependencies path to run React-native but I still don't know how to configure that. Could someone help me, please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wbcS.jpg)

## my zfille config path:

## If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

## Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.

```
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

## rbenv

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"`
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I had solved this problem by changing Ruby version on .ruby-version or Gemfile